# Calling a DELETE action appears to reset my session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an older Rails application that was Rails 2.x and I've upgraded to Rails 3.0.12 (Ruby 1.9.3)

After going through the upgrade most of the site is working.  However, the current user is simply stored in session (session[:user_id])  Every controller checks that session to authenticate the user before allowing the action to be executed.

When I use the data_method="delete" to call a delete action on a controller, it appears that the session is reset and I can't tell why (no place in the code is reset_session called)

This only happens when calling the action from a browser (either from a link or from an ajax call)  When I call the action in my specs, it works as expected.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `rake routes` for any unexpected DELETE routing?

Comment: Nothing in `routes` looks unusual.

Comment: is there any `https` involved? are you doing this over subdomains?

Comment: No and No.  It does it from localhost when I'm just running rail s and does it from a server running passenger/apache on http